# Program works, but then fails when I write it inside Module

Tags: programming, warning-messages, core-language, scoping, assignment

I'm new to Wolfram Language; I'm trying to get used to it by writing a bunch of code and programs, being one of them the algorithm for the bisection method.

When I write the algorithm outside of a Module, it works:

```
f[x_] := Sin[x] - 2^x + Log[10, x] + 5
a = 1.0;
b = 3.0;
e = 10^-8;
nmax = 100;

fa = f[a];
fb = f[b];
If[fa fb > 0, Print["Error. Signos Iguales."]; Exit[]]
error = b - a;
For[n = 1, n <= nmax, n++,
 error = error/2;
 c = error + a;
 fc = f[c];
 If[Abs[error] < e, Print["Convergencia"]; Break[]];
 If[fa fc < 0, b = c; fb = fc, a = c; fa = fc];
 ]
Print[c]
Plot[f[x], {x, a, b}]
```

[image]

However, I want to properly write the program by writing it inside a Module:

```
f[x_] := Sin[x] - 2^x + Log[10, x] + 5

biseccion[a_,b_,e_,nmax_]:=Module[{fa,fb,error,n,c,fc},
fa = f[a];
fb = f[b];
If[fa fb > 0, Print["Error. Signos Iguales."]; Exit[]];
error = b - a;
For[n = 1, n <= nmax, n++,
 error = error/2;
 c = error + a;
 fc = f[c];
 If[Abs[error] < e, Print["Convergencia"]; Break[]];
 If[fa fc < 0, b = c; fb = fc, a = c; fa = fc];
 ];
Print[c];
Plot[f[x], {x, a, b}]
]
```

And, when I do so, I get the following error:

[image]

I'm sure the solution is very simple, and that this is just a newbie question.. but i have been wrapping my head around this for hours and can not solve it.

Also, now that I'm here, do you know wether it is possible to pass the  `f[x]`  as an argument to  `biseccion` instead of just writing it before declaring the module?

*The variable named as $e$ in the aforewritten codes is actually named as $\epsilon$ in the code I wrote in Mathematica.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I hope you will become a regular contributor.  To get started,  1) take the introductory [tour] now, 2) when you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge, 3) remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t), and 4) give help too, by answering questions in your areas of expertise.

Comment: Take a look at the answer on [Attempting to make an assignment to the argument of a function](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/18737/27951) in the FAQ [What are the most common pitfalls awaiting new users?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/18393/what-are-the-most-common-pitfalls-awaiting-new-users)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As defined, `a` is the name of an argument pattern, not a mutable symbol. By invoking the function as `bissecion[1.0...` you're defining it to be `1.0`. Thus, `a=c` is rewritten as `1.0=c`, which is nonsensical.

Good practice is to list each mutable symbol in your `Module` definition, and initialize them to arguments as necessary.